# Передача картинки с сервера на клиент

Tags: java, android, изображения, tcp

Мне нужно принять картинку с сервера на клиент. 
Есть мобильное приложение, на котором по нажатию кнопки я должен вывести на экран в imageView, фото с веб-камеры, которое содержится на сервере. Я искал и понял, что мне нужно как-то принять и сохранить на телефоне это изображение, и уже потом вывести его. Есть ли способ проще?

Используя TCP соединение.

Comment: Кто должен инициировать обновление картинки, клиент или сервер?

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.**
 Сделать изображение доступным по ссылке http://mysite.ru/imaga/imageABC, тогда в андроид приложеннии нужно просто читать картинку с url. Реализация серверной части может быть различной в зависимости от того как много и как часто картинки меняются.
**Вариант 2.**
Передавать картику через Rest как массив байтов

Comment: Михаил не знаю как еще вам написать, подскажите как реализовать серверную часть как в 1 варианте? Проект написан на Java, использован Spring-Hibernate-Jpa.

Comment: @Android-EE посмотрите тут http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data правда по англицки но читать не надо нужно только код скопировать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже решил проблему)